# Deezer SDK returning Null description

Tags: java, android, parsing, deezer

I am currently trying to use the Deezer Android SDK to read a users playlists, However when I call `getDescription()` on the returned playlist object the function returns null on a playlist I know for sure has a description. I'm not sure if this is due to an error I made or a bug with the SDK... Any help is appreciated :)

My Code:

```
private void readPlaylists(DeezerConnect deezerConnect){
        DeezerRequest request = DeezerRequestFactory.requestCurrentUserPlaylists();
        AsyncDeezerTask task = new AsyncDeezerTask(deezerConnect, new JsonRequestListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onResult(Object o, Object o1) {
               List<Playlist> retList = (List<Playlist>) o;
               for(Playlist p : retList){
                   Log.d(TAG, "description: " + p.getDescription()); //RETURNS NULL
                   userPlaylists.add(new MyPlaylist(p));
               }
               startMainActivity();
            }
            @Override
            public void onUnparsedResult(String s, Object o) {
                startErrorActivity("Unparsed response: " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception e, Object o) 
                startErrorActivity(e.getMessage());
            }
        });
        task.execute(request);
    }
```

**EDIT:** So I checked and turns out the API doesn't return a description in the playlist object, Am i missing something or is this a bug?

```
data": [
    {
      "id": "7734515682",
      "title": "Deezer Playlist",
      "duration": 791,
      "public": true,
      "is_loved_track": false,
      "collaborative": false,
      "nb_tracks": 4,
      "fans": 0,
      "link": "https:\/\/www.deezer.com\/playlist\/7734515682",
      "picture": "https:\/\/api.deezer.com\/2.0\/playlist\/7734515682\/image",
      "picture_small": "https:\/\/cdns-images.dzcdn.net\/images\/cover\/4102875e1a8b47d6c958f0b1a998d1ca-3cab79eaa87e1dd7bdd594cd6f36f426-790c3f0b759817585b35caf5d7fe2fca-570d76c222d1d1d3751cab1c2ca9ad00\/56x56-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "picture_medium": "https:\/\/cdns-images.dzcdn.net\/images\/cover\/4102875e1a8b47d6c958f0b1a998d1ca-3cab79eaa87e1dd7bdd594cd6f36f426-790c3f0b759817585b35caf5d7fe2fca-570d76c222d1d1d3751cab1c2ca9ad00\/250x250-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "picture_big": "https:\/\/cdns-images.dzcdn.net\/images\/cover\/4102875e1a8b47d6c958f0b1a998d1ca-3cab79eaa87e1dd7bdd594cd6f36f426-790c3f0b759817585b35caf5d7fe2fca-570d76c222d1d1d3751cab1c2ca9ad00\/500x500-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "picture_xl": "https:\/\/cdns-images.dzcdn.net\/images\/cover\/4102875e1a8b47d6c958f0b1a998d1ca-3cab79eaa87e1dd7bdd594cd6f36f426-790c3f0b759817585b35caf5d7fe2fca-570d76c222d1d1d3751cab1c2ca9ad00\/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "checksum": "-----------",
      "tracklist": "https:\/\/api.deezer.com\/2.0\/playlist\/7734515682\/tracks",
      "creation_date": "2020-06-05 14:26:54",
      "time_add": 1591367293,
      "time_mod": 1591367293,
      "creator": {
        "id": "-----",
        "name": "----",
        "tracklist": "https:\/\/api.deezer.com\/2.0\/user\/-----\/flow",
        "type": "user"
      },
      "type": "playlist"
    }
```

Comment: Is your Object o also returning null? What does your stacktrace say?
Maybe check deezer's example UserPlaylistsActivity here: https://github.com/deezer/android-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/deezer/sdk/sample/UserPlaylistsActivity.java

Comment: My object returns fine, I can get the title and image its just the description I'm having problems with, And I consulted with the example already :)

Comment: Hmm..  If you're sure it has a description and it still doesn't return one, maybe you should open a new issue on github.